# Spawning a supervised process to report a heartbeat periodically

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

I'm trying to spawn a process that will post an HTTP request every five seconds to report it's heartbeat to a server. The code I have is:

```
defmodule MyModule.Heartbeat do
  def start_link do
    spawn_link(fn ->
      :timer.apply_interval(:timer.seconds(5), __MODULE__, :beat, [])
    end)
  end

  defp beat do
    HTTPoison.post "https://myserver/heartbeat
  end
end

defmodule MyModule.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
     children = [
       worker(MyModule.Heartbeat, [])
     ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

However, when I try to start the app, it exits with the following error:

```
[info] Application my_module exited: MyModule.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: MyModule.Heartbeat
    ** (EXIT) #PID<0.535.0>
```

All I need is some process that will run as part of the supervision tree and send it's request in the specified interval. It doesn't need to be able to receive any messages itself, and I'm not too bothered about the particular implementation.

Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong here that's preventing this process from starting, and if there might be a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 mistakes in your code:

1. `:timer.apply_interval/4` returns immediately, and thus the anonymous
   function passed to `spawn_link` in `MyModule.Heartbeat.start_link/0` terminates
   soon after executing that line, causing `:timer` to remove the interval from
   its queue, and not calling `MyModule.Heartbeat.beat/0` ever.

   You can solve this by adding a `:timer.sleep(:infinity)` as the last
   expression, which makes your process sleep forever.
2. `MyModule.Heartbeat.beat/0` needs to be a public function so that the
   anonymous function passed to `spawn_link` can call it.
3. `MyModule.Heartbeat.start_link/0` needs to return `{:ok, pid}` on success.
   `spawn_link` returns just a pid.

Final code after these 3 changes:

```
defmodule MyModule.Heartbeat do
  def start_link do
    pid = spawn_link(fn ->
      :timer.apply_interval(:timer.seconds(5), __MODULE__, :beat, [])
      :timer.sleep(:infinity)
    end)
    {:ok, pid}
  end

  def beat do
    IO.puts "beat"
  end
end

defmodule MyModule.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
     children = [
       worker(MyModule.Heartbeat, [])
     ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
iex(1)> MyModule.Supervisor.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.84.0>}
iex(2)> beat
beat
beat
beat
```

---

I'm not sure if you even need all this setup as an exception raised by the function
passed to `:timer.apply_interval` does not affect the calling process. The
following script keeps attempting to run the function even though it always raises an
exception:

```
defmodule Beat do
  def beat do
    raise "hey"
  end
end

:timer.apply_interval(:timer.seconds(1), Beat, :beat, [])
:timer.sleep(:infinity)
```

Output:

```
$ elixir a.exs

16:00:43.207 [error] Process #PID<0.53.0> raised an exception
** (RuntimeError) hey
    a.exs:3: Beat.beat/0

16:00:44.193 [error] Process #PID<0.54.0> raised an exception
** (RuntimeError) hey
    a.exs:3: Beat.beat/0

16:00:45.193 [error] Process #PID<0.55.0> raised an exception
** (RuntimeError) hey
    a.exs:3: Beat.beat/0
```

Comment: Why does the heartbeat continue to work after using :infinity for sleep? shouldn't the whole thing freeze up and stop?

Comment: `:timer.sleep(:infinity)` "freezes" only the process (Erlang Process) executing that code. The `:timer` application is still running and calling the function we asked it to at the specified interval.